# Create manytomany to user with value

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

I am building an application where I need to add to the user model 'skills'. These skills are created and added by the user being this also a model.
I want to add to this skills, related with a many to many relationship, a value. This value will be a number from 1 to 10 specifing the level of the user at a particular skill.
So that I need to relate a level to each skill added to the user.

models.py

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Perfil(AbstractUser):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, null=True)
```

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about ManyToManyField `through` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the value to the many to many table. In order to be able to do this you would need to create a custom many to many table.

See [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for an example.